# Setting Up TPM on Intel NUC running Ubuntu 14.04.1-Desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: 14.04, encryption, intel-nuc, tpm

I am trying to secure data on an Intel NUC DE3815TYHE. It has a TPM Module on it and I have been searching to find if anyone has successfully done this on a NUC.

I have set it up for Secure Boot in BIOS, installed Trousers and tried to follow a guide I found for Linux but it is too generic and some of the commands are different. TPM Version 1.2 is installed on the NUC.

Should I be installing Ubuntu with Encryption or Encrypting the User area?

Any suggestions or guides are welcome :)

Regards

Toco